Automatic reload with Ktor Server running KMP/Compose MP WASM/JS
I am wondering if it is at all possible to get the Ktor Server to watch the composeApp folder at all? It is watching the server and common folders (the build folders inside these two), but not the composeApp folder, which is where my .js and .wasm files are which I would like to watch.
Seemingly not possible, there is no information about this particular issue anywhere from what I can see, but perhaps someone has done this in a way that works?
ktor {
    development = true
    deployment {
        port = 8080
    }
    application {
        modules = [ com.jakkej.timesheet.ApplicationKt.module ]
    }
}

Above is my application.conf file, if I add watch = [] it only supports stuff like "classes" or "resources" (without the quotation marks ofc), but nothing custom like myApp/composeApp/build directory, unless I've misunderstood something that is.
I've tried full paths, just composeApp, most logical things, but watch seems to only support a few predetermined paths.

Unfortunately, Ktor can only reload Java classes.

Did you find any solution to this issue ?

No I ended up running it on my old works server, who I was doing this for, which only supports PHP. Ended up just making endpoints with PHP instead.
